# The limit of a Nasty Summation

Tags: limits, derivatives, summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

I'm trying to evaluate the limit as h approachs 0 of the sum from k = 0 to n of:

$\frac{1}{h^n}(-1)^{k+n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{(x+kh)^2-2(x+kh)+17}$

If it helps, it's the limit definition of the nth derivative of $\frac{1}{x^2-2x+17}$

Any thoughts?

Comment: Let $c>b^2$, then $f(x)=\frac1{x^2-2bx+c}=\frac{1}{(x-b-i\sqrt{c-b^2})(x-b+i\sqrt{c-b^2})}=\frac1{2i\sqrt{c-b^2}}\Big(\frac1{x-b-i\sqrt{c-b^2}}-\frac1{x-b+i\sqrt{c-b^2}}\Big)$
$$f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{\sqrt{c-b^2}}\,\Im\frac1{(x-b-i\sqrt{c-b^2})^{n+1}}$$
$$=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{\sqrt{c-b^2}}\left(\frac1{x^2-2b+c}\right)^{\frac{n+1}2}\sin\left((n+1)\arctan\frac{\sqrt{c-b^2}}{|x-b|}\right)$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Where did the formula for f^(n)(x) come from? Also, quicking plotting this into Desmos shows it's not quite the same as f^(n)(x). Is this an approximation? Is there an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment.  Let's check.

$\displaystyle \qquad\sin x=\frac{|\tan x|}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2x}};\,\cos x=\frac1{\sqrt{1+\tan^2x}}\tag{0}$

$\displaystyle n=0$
$$ f^{(0)}(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{c-b^2}}\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-2bx+c}}\sin\left(\arctan\frac{\sqrt{c-b^2}}{|x-b|}\right)$$
$$=\frac1{\sqrt{c-b^2}}\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-2bx+c}}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{c-b^2}}{|x-b|}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{c-b^2}{(x-b)^2}}}=\frac{1}{x^2-2bx+c}\tag{1}$$
$\displaystyle n=1$
$$\qquad f^{(1)}(x)=-\frac1{\sqrt{c-b^2}}\frac1{x^2-2bx+c}2\sin\left(\arctan\frac{\sqrt{c-b^2}}{|x-b|}\right)\cos\left(\arctan\frac{\sqrt{c-b^2}}{|x-b|}\right)$$
$$=-\frac2{\sqrt{c-b^2}}\frac1{x^2-2bx+c}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{c-b^2}}{|x-b|}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{c-b^2}{(x-b)^2}}}\frac1{\sqrt{1+\frac{c-b^2}{(x-b)^2}}}=-2\frac{x-b}{(x^2-2bx+c)^2}$$

In the comment I used $$ \Im\frac {d^{n-1}}{dp^{n-1}}\left(\frac1{p-iq}\right)=\Im\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(p-iq)^n}=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!\,\Im\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{p^2+q^2}}e^{i\arctan\frac qp}\right)^n$$
$$=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!\frac{\sin(n\arctan\frac qp)}{(p^2+q^2)^\frac n2}$$

Comment: Ah I think that makes sense now. I have one more question: why are we only taking the imaginary part? Thanks!

Comment: The imaginary part appears in a natural way, because$$\frac1{x^2-2bx+c}=\frac{1}{(x-b-i\sqrt{c-b^2})(x-b+i\sqrt{c-b^2})}$$
$$=\frac1{\sqrt{c-b^2}}\,\frac1{2i}\Big(\frac1{x-b-i\sqrt{c-b^2}}-\frac1{x-b+i\sqrt{c-b^2}}\Big)$$
$$=\frac1{\sqrt{c-b^2}}\,\frac1{2i}\Big(\frac1{x-b-i\sqrt{c-b^2}}-\Big(\frac1{x-b-i\sqrt{c-b^2}}\Big)^*\Big)=\frac1{\sqrt{c-b^2}}\,\Im\,\frac1{x-b-i\sqrt{c-b^2}}$$

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much!